# How do you convert a string to a 32-bit big-endian number in Java?

Tags: java, websocket, endianness

I'm trying to get some websockets working and I need to convert a string (or a long) to a 32-bit big-endian number.

How do you do this in Java?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Java [writes out values in big-endian/network order](http://books.google.com/books?id=42etT_9-_9MC&pg=PT148&lpg=PT148&dq=java+big+endian+output&source=bl&ots=xx7P1CmOaD&sig=IP1PRQiMA0Ox3TYpi0od45S16MI&hl=en&ei=xjPjTPy7OIOB8gap7IHaDg&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=10&ved=0CFQQ6AEwCQ) so you're in luck in that regard.

Java int values are always [signed](http://www.artima.com/weblogs/viewpost.jsp?thread=7555) [32-bit](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html) value too.

Regarding sending a long in 32-bits, be sure the value fits in 32 bits or you're going to lose data. You're just not able to send 5 gallons in a 2.5 gallon bucket.

You can use the [Integer.parseInt(String)](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#parseInt%28java.lang.String%29) method to get an int value:

```
int x = Integer.parseInt("12345");
```

or [Integer.valueOf(String)](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#valueOf%28java.lang.String%29) if you want an Integer.

```
Integer x = Integer.valueOf("12345");
```

Answer (score 2):

`Integer.valueOf(str);`